# ExtJS pass values to store.filter from URL

Tags: extjs, store, extjs3

Here is an example of two of my URLs:

http://myurl.com/viewer/?color=red

http://myurl.com/viewer/?color=red&priority=1

Okay, what I am needing to do is to be able to filter for either of these situations coming up - meaning that the script will accept the URL with either one or two parameters passed and then use store.filter to filter out the data being shown on the screen.

Here is the code I'm using - I can get it to work if I put in both in the store.filter but if only one is set (like the first URL), then it crashes.

What do I need to do to be able to accept one or both dynamically?

I'm totally stuck......

```
var events_ds = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad: true,
            autoDestroy: true,
            url: '<% $base %>json/events/viewer.json',
            storeId: 'events_ds',
            idProperty: 'id',
            fields: [ 'id', 'precedence', 'affectedWWN', 'eventType', 'color', 'CollectTime' ],
            listeners:
                    { 'load': function(store)
                            {
                             store.filter([
                                {property: 'color' , value: $_GET['color'] , anyMatch: true , caseSensitive: false},
                                {property: 'precedence' , value: $_GET['priority'] , anyMatch: true , caseSensitive: false}
                            ]);
                            }
                    }

    });
```

Comment: yes, but I've tried a couple of ways to put an if statement in there but I'm not getting the syntax correctly for some reason